# Access pub/sub message in cloudbuild pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I want to trigger a cloudbuild pipeline in response to a Pub/Sub message and access the message contents in one of the steps.

For example:

gcloud command to send Pub/Sub message, triggering pipeline:

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish my-pubsub-topic \
  --message='{"name_a": "value_a", "name_b": "value_b"}'
```

my cloudbuild.yml:

```
steps:

  - name: "ubuntu"
    args: ["bash", "-c", "message['name_a']"]

  - name: python
    entrypoint: python
    args: ["-m", "parse_message.py"]
```

parse_message.py:

```
import json

json.loads(message)

print(message['name_a'])
```

What can I put in my ubuntu step or my `parse_message.py` script to output something like `"value_a"`?

Comment: Do  you want to trigger a Cloud Build pipeline on a PubSub message?

Comment: You could incorporate piece of code responsible for subscribing and receiving messages from Pub/Sub in your `parse_message.py`. E.g. using [pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) or [push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) subscriptions. Let me know what you think about that approach.